# Using VMware Fusion on Yosemite, how can I prevent crashes with sleep wake failure?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, vmware, virtualization

I am using VMware Fusion 7.1.0 on Mac OS 10.10.1 Yosemite. Every evening, I send my iMac to sleep. The next morning the mac usually sits in login mask - so it has rebooted. After login, I get "sleep wake failure".

How can I mitigate this? Are there any known workarounds?

I had this problem before with Mac OS 10.9 and VMware Fusion 6 but found no workaround. It seems, that with one of the updates of 10.9 the problem went away or was way more seldom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After talking to VMware support, there are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Open your Mac's system preferences, go to Energy Saver and disable the option "Put hard disks to sleep when possible". With that option deactivated, I had no sleep wake failures.
2. Pause or suspend your virtual machines prior to sending your Mac to sleep.

Comment: Point 1) does not work for me, only point 2). And point 2) is the one I really want to avoid...

Comment: I find it a shame that a commercial app like VMWare Fusion which used to work flawlessly for years suddenly has such a huge problem and doesn't seem to be able to fix it in a reasonable time. Is there a way we can put VMWare under pressure to resolve the issue?

Comment: I also wanted to avoid point 2, but it seems to be necessary on my case. However, using **pause/unpause** is not as slow as shut down/restart, so apparently this is acceptable to me. I will post later if I have any new findings on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem everytime I upgrade the OS. By turning off app nap for the entire Mac I was able to resolve the issue on Yosemite.  See the link below.

http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/13/disable-app-nap-mac-os-x/

Comment: Don't you think its enough to disable app nap for VMware Fusion? I don't see how doing this should resolve problems with VMware crashing the mac.

Comment: This no longer works.