# OSX crashes and reboots several hours after going to "sleep" (lid closed)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro as my work laptop. When I go home, I close the lid and take the laptop with me. Very often, the next time I open my laptop I find that the OS restarted "because of a problem". This reboot may happen several hours after the lid is closed, as the sound from my laptop back indicates.

What is the best way to understand / debug why this is happening? Can I get some useful information from log files?

---

The laptop is `MacBookPro11,3`, with Intel Core i7 processor, and 16 GB of RAM. The programs that are usually running before crash are iTerm, Finder, Microsoft Outlook, and Chrome. I also run a Vagrant VM with a bunch of processes in it for work. My coworkers run exactly the same codebase and none of them is having the same problem.

Comment: Can you give details on you MacBook, such as the model date and what processor, memory, etc. as well as what apps you use before the crash/going to sleep.

Comment: i am having the same issue,i would like to know if this is a fairly recent happening? my issue started 1 1/2 - 2 days ago, perhaps if thats when yours started than it might be connected? but yes and i notice the time also varies, even walking up and down stairs is enough time for when i open it to say it needed to restart "because of a problem". here are some of my stats Model Name: MacBook Pro Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,2 Processor Name: Intel Core i7 Processor Speed: 2.2 GHz Number of Processors: 1 Total Number of Cores: 4 L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB L3 Cache: 6 MB Memory: 16 GB Boot ROM

Comment: My problem has been around since I was given a Mac at work, May 2015. It's definitely been around since I switched to Yousemite.

Comment: My issue can be a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169555/using-vmware-fusion-on-yosemite-how-can-i-prevent-crashes-with-sleep-wake-failu as it mentions problems with `VMware Fusion` which we use as a hypervisor. I have this feeling because VMvare is listed in the crash report among other things.

Comment: I also have this issue on my Mac OSX Yosemite frequently if I don't turn off a VMware Fusion 8.1.0 VM

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was related exactly to VMWare. Before putting my laptop to sleep I suspend the VM and the issue doesn't happen. That's a "pause" button in the VMWare UI.

[image]

**Edit**:

Looks like VMWare sleep functionality is buggy. I once got my entire VM getting to the point of no return. I simply use `vagrant suspend` these days before putting my laptop to sleep. No need to bring up VMWare UI.

Comment: [Combining with changing some of mac's Energy Saver preferences](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/169683/116146), this is a working solution for me and a colleague I talked to yesterday. At least, pausing/unpausing doesn't take as much time as with shut down/restart.